# code not running on device/emulator

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I m new to cordova/ionic. 
I have a cordova project which i want to run either on android device or emulator.
When i run the command : ionic cordova run android.
I get the following error :

---

> Detected locally installed Ionic CLI, but it's too old--using global
>   CLI.
>
> > cordova platform add android --save Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@7.0.0 Error: Failed to fetch platform
> >     cordova-android@7.0.0 Probably this is either a connection problem, or
> >     platform spec is incorrect. Check your connection and platform
> >     name/version/URL. Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error
> >     output:

---

in the code platform android already exists, but when i check its version it i s, android~6.3.0.
I have tried a number of things to resolve it which includes, reinstalling cordova, android.
Can anyone have a solution for it.
The code was written around a year back and now i have all the latest versions installed in my system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is android platform was not added properly. Therefore you have to add respective Android Platform into your Project.

Before adding run :

> cordova platform remove android

After run :

> cordova platform add android@6.0.0

if you develop on windows enviroment You can check the version of Android provided by Cordova under :

```
C:/Users/%USER%/.cordova/lib/npm-cache/cordova-android
```

You may also want to try adding --nofetch to the command, which will use the pre-7.x behavior. See [Cordova 7 fails to add android platform](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12767)

Comment: i have tried cordova platform remove android,it gives me error : Removing platform android from config.xml file...
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Puja.DESKTOP-1RKA5NV\Projects\inte\inte\node_modules\.bin\create
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! Refusing to delete C:\Users\Puja.DESKTOP-1RKA5NV\Projects\inte\inte\node_modules\.bin\create: is outside C:\Users\Puja.DESKTOP-1RKA5NV\Projects\inte\inte\node_modules\cordova-android and not a link
npm ERR! File exists: C:\Users\Puja.DESKTOP-1RKA5NV\Projects\inte\inte\node_modules\.bin\create
npm ERR!

Comment: This is user permission issue on your machine I guess. Somehow you can delete the platform folder from your project and run cordova platform add android@6.0.0

Comment: That issue is resolved by removing android platform and reinstalling android and npm again. Thanks

Comment: I m able to run the code on the real android device using atom and visual studio but i m not able to debug and check the code response, i also tried --lac to display the log on terminal.But it is also not working. Can you please suggest something.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it by firstly updating your android sdk manager with all the latest updates and also update its gradle. Then try to firstly remove the android platform using command 
CORDOVA PLATFORM REM ANDROID 
and then add android platform using command 
CORDOVA PLATFORM ADD ANDROID.

Comment: i m getting this error 
 when i try to remove it. C:\Users\Puja.DESKTOP\inte>cordova platform remove android
Removing platform android from config.xml file...
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Puja.DESKTOP-\inte\node_modules\.bin\create
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! Refusing to delete C:\Users\Puja.DESKTOP-\inte\node_modules\.bin\create: is outside C:\Users\Puja.DESKTOP-\inte\node_modules\cordova-android and not a link
npm ERR! File exists: C:\Users\Puja.DESKTOP-\inte\node_modules\.bin\create
npm ERR! Move it away